# Altair: How to format times in axis labels in a non-UTC non-local timezone?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to plot some time series data with Altair, and have the times (on the axis labels) show up in a fixed timezone that's not UTC and not the user's local timezone. As far as I can tell from the docs, those are the only options supported (local being the default, and [UTC can be used as described here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/times_and_dates.html#using-utc-time)) Is there a way to configure this that I'm missing?

Using the times directly as string values is not an option because this is not supported with the interactive selection interval.

Another alternative I looked into was formatting the timestamp into the target timezone in Python and passing it to Altair as a string, but that didn't seem to work either:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
  "temp": [-28, -28, -27],
  "timestamp": [1706043000, 1706043060, 1706043120]
})
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], utc=True, unit='s')
data['formatted_time'] = data['time'].dt.tz_convert('Antarctica/South_Pole').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

selection = alt.selection_interval(bind='scales', encodings=['x'])
(alt.Chart(data)
  .mark_line()
  # Errors out: Unrecognized signal name: "formatted_time"
  # .encode(x=alt.X('time:T', axis=alt.Axis(values=alt.ExprRef('formatted_time'))), y='temp')
  # Shows nothing on the X axis?
  .encode(x=alt.X('time:T', axis=alt.Axis(values=data['formatted_time'].values)), y='temp')
  .add_selection(selection))
```

[image: graph with no values on the x axis]

Comment: I think this might be possible using another scale as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71955613, but I haven't quite figured out how to wire it up in Altair (the extra scale that's not attached to a chart)

Comment: Can you modify: `(alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(x=alt.X('time:T', axis=alt.Axis(values=data['formatted_time'].values)), y='temp').add_selection(selection))` to `chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(x=alt.X('time:T', axis=alt.Axis(title='Time (Antarctica/South_Pole)', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')), y='temp').add_selection(selection)`?

Comment: With that I'm getting values on x-axis as this [image](https://imgur.com/a/B8bflyv). I'm just not sure if that's something you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your code:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
  "temp": [-28, -28, -27],
  "timestamp": [1706043000, 1706043060, 1706043120]
})
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], utc=True, unit='s')
data['formatted_time'] = data['time'].dt.tz_convert('Antarctica/South_Pole').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

selection = alt.selection_interval(bind='scales', encodings=['x'])
chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('time:T', axis=alt.Axis(title='Time (Antarctica/South_Pole)', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
    y='temp'
).add_selection(selection)

chart
```

The above shows the time in a fixed timezone and produces the following interactive plot:
[image]

Comment: @Ro.oT See my comment about DST on the other answer - also relevant here.

Comment: I see. I guess in that case using `tz_localize` should work since it's supposed to map naive timestamps to timezone-aware timestamps. Also, as per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) it handles the DST conversion for both sequential and ambiguous times.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this answer from @jakevdp will shed some light on the topic:

[Date parsing and when to use utc/TimeUnits in Vega Lite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319836/date-parsing-and-when-to-use-utc-timeunits-in-vega-lite)

If you switch to **type:Ordinal** instead of temporal you may get the results you are looking for.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Bump chart",
  "width": 500,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2024-01-25T10:00:00", "result": "PASSED"},
      {"date": "2024-01-26T10:00:00", "result": "FAILED"},
      {"date": "2024-01-27T10:00:00", "result": "PASSED"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "yearmonthdatehoursminutes",
      "title": "Date-time"
    },
    "y": {"field": "result", "type": "nominal", "title": "Results"}
  }
}
```

Here is how to pass epoch times also if this helps:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Bump chart",
  "width": 500,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "1706173200000", "result": "PASSED"},
      {"date": "1706259600000", "result": "PASSED"},
      {"date": "1706346000000", "result": "FAILED"}
    ],
    "format": {"parse": {"date": "date:'%Q'"}}
  },
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "yearmonthdatehoursminutes",
      "title": "Date-time"
    },
    "y": {"field": "result", "type": "nominal", "title": "Results"}
  }
}
```